# Загрузить изображение и тут же его отобразить

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы, после выбора изображения (пользователь нажал "Загрузить" и выбрал изображение), можно было с ним работать, к примеру, узнать размеры, и тут же получить код самого изображения в base64 и, тем самым, вывести? base64 нужен для хранения изображения на сервере.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы вывести изображение, можно засунуть его в `canvas` в месте, где должно быть изображение, загруженное пользователем. Также `canvas` имеет метод `toDataURL`, работайте с ним ;)